# Can't reference to System.Xml.XPath.dll

Tags: html, windows-phone

I have created a windows phone Project that use HTML Agility Pack. I tried to reference to `System.Xml.XPath.dll` file but a error message say:

> A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project.

I'm using VS 2013 and Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.tareqateik.com/html-agility-pack%E2%80%93windows-phone-8#.U1Az6lWSwtF), You need to use Silverlight v4 of the dll and not v5.